# Get the last revision id of any given entity?

Tags: 7, entities

Is there a single, unified method in Drupal 7 to get the last revision id for any given entity object?  If so, what is that method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [`entity_extract_ids()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_extract_ids/7) is the quickest you'll get:

> Helper function to extract id, vid, and bundle name from an entity.

e.g.

```
list($nid, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids('node', $some_node);
```

Comment: My issue with this is that it gives the *next* revision of an item.  I'm looking for the last revision stored in the database.

Comment: That will give you the _current_ revision ID, which by normal definition is the last in the database - what are you looking for if not the current revision?

Comment: Well obvioulsy you're right :) I was doing something really dumb.

Comment: A minor clarification. When you call `entity_extract_ids` in hook_entity_update, `$vid` will be equal to the new revision of the entity. So, while this answer is technically correct, you might be using logic in `hook_entity_update` that acts as if the new entity revision id has not been determined yet, when in fact it already has. A better name for `hook_entity_update` might be `hook_entity_updated`...

Answer (score 0):

Calling {entity_type}_load for any entity will load the most recent version **(caution - see comment below)**

For example for a node calling `node_load(1)` will load the most recent version of that node.

The revision id will be found in the vid property.

```
$node = node_load(1); // load the most recent version of node with id 1
$most_recent_version_id = $node->vid; // this is where you find the version id
```

Or for a user:

```
$user = user_load(1);
$most_recent_version_id = $user->vid; // this users version id
```

Comment: This is not quite true node_load(1) will load the published version of the node. Which might not necessarily be the most recent.

Comment: Great point @DavidCoote

Answer (score 0):

```
$nid = 1;
$vid = db_query('SELECT vid FROM {node_revision} WHERE nid = :nid ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 0,1', array(':nid' => $nid))->fetchField();
$oNode = node_load($nid, $vid);
```

The above code will load the latest revision for NID 1 ($nid = 1, in this case) by finding the highest node_revision.vid.  It then loads that revision into $oNode.

Comment: Though this may be an answer to the question, please include some explanation of what the code does.