# Get a list of revision IDs for any given entity?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

What's the most uniform method for getting a list of revision IDs for any given entity, programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the last revision id of any given entity?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106882/get-the-last-revision-id-of-any-given-entity)

Comment: Interestingly enough I'm the one who asked that question O_o. I believe the problem I'm having is slightly different so I'm going to alter my question to fit the context, ever so slightly.

Comment: i know, that confused me greatly :)

Comment: Okay so I updated this question so that it's no longer a duplicate. Now I'm going to udpdate the other question to clarify the issue.

Comment: There are an additional 3 votes to close since I last viewed this question (and also changed the question). It's really not appropriate to close this issue anymore as the linked "duplicate" question is no longer a duplicate. This question asks to get the entire revision ID list, not get the last revision of an entity. Please remove your votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I'll leave it here because it might be useful to someone down the road.

You can use this function to get a list of all revisions ids for any given entity.

```
/**
 * Get a revision id list for a particular entity.
 */
function get_entity_revision_list($type, $entity) {
  $info = entity_get_info($type);
  if (!isset($info['revision table'])) {
    // If this entity does not track revisions then return FALSE.
    return FALSE;
  }
  if (!isset($info['entity keys']['revision'])) {
    // If for whatever reason a revision table was defined, but no revision key
    // then also return FALSE.
    return FALSE;
  }
  $revisions = db_select($info['revision table'], 'r')
    ->fields('r', array($info['entity keys']['revision']))
    ->condition($info['entity keys']['id'], $entity->{$info['entity keys']['id']})
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc($info['entity keys']['revision']);
  return array_keys($revisions);
}
```

Comment: Please notice that depending on your particular scenario, this funcion can be optimized. Although the function above expects a full entity as second parameter, $entity is only used once, to get the Entity ID. So with little modifications on the code, you can get your entity's revisions from its ID. There's no need to load a full entity for this function to run.